# Reduced Costs and Nonbasic Indices in Linear Programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I am having a hard time understanding reduced costs and was wondering if anyone could help me out with this problem?

Consider a linear programming problem in standard form and suppose that x∗ is an optimal basic feasible solution. Consider an optimal basis associated with x∗. Let B and N be the set of basic and nonbasic indices, respectively. Let I be the set of nonbasic indices i for which the corresponding reduced costs c ̄i are zero.

(a) Show that if I is empty, then x∗ is the only optimal solution

(b) Show that x∗ is the unique optimal solution if and only if the following linear programming problem has an optimal value of zero:

maximize   (sum of xi over i within I)
subject to Ax=b
           xi=0 , i within N/I
           xi>=0 , i within B union I

Comment: Consider using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve readability. What are your thoughts on the problem?